# On a paper on almost polynomial rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

I was studying a paper on Almost polynomial rings and unable to understand the blue underlined statement. Could one please elaborate how is that coming ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The ring $R$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ with some restrictions on denominators of the coefficients (the coefficient of $X^n$ must be of the form $\frac{a}{p_1^{k_1}\ldots p_r^{k_r}}$ with $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k_1 + \cdots + k_r \le n$).

The ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the ring you obtain by inverting every prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ except $p$ :

$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{Q}, \exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, \, x = \frac{a}{b}, \, p \nmid b\right\}$$

Taking the tensor product of $R$ with $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ adds an inverse to every prime except $p$ to the ring $R$. So it amounts to lifting the restrictions on the denominators, except for the prime $p$. You get a the subring of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ where the coefficient of $X^n$ must be of the form $\frac{a}{b p^{k}}$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $p \nmid b$ and $k \le n$, which is exactly $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[X/p]$.